# Too many rake processes spawning on AWS Beanstalk rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sidekiq, ebextensions

I'm deploying a Ruby on Rails application on AWS Beanstalk. The application also needs a [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) process for background jobs. There's also a [sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers) process running to listen on messages from a RabbitMQ instance.

I created an upstart process for sidekiq using ebextensions from the [process outlined here](https://medium.com/@benhansen/setting-up-sidekiq-redis-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-elasticache-2efeb32935fe#.x3va8f1js). Using the same outline, I created another upstart process for running the sneakers rake task. All the config files are [here in this gist](https://gist.github.com/kitwalker12/0313e0edd66e5bfa7aed78f6890fab9d).

The deploy runs fine and I can see the sidekiq and sneaker processes running, but after a few deploys I began seeing a number of rake processes being spawned which are taking up database connections.

```
[root@ip-XXX ec2-user]# ps aux | grep '[/]opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake'
webapp   13563  0.0  2.2 1400644 184988 ?      Sl   01:41   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   13866  0.7  2.3 694804 193620 ?       Sl   01:42   0:10 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   14029  0.0  2.2 1400912 183700 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   14046  0.0  2.2 1400912 183812 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   14048  0.0  2.2 1400912 183804 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   14073  0.0  2.2 1400912 183712 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   14158  0.0  2.2 827056 187972 ?       Sl   Nov23   4:23 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   19139  0.9  2.3 694744 193388 ?       Sl   01:47   0:10 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   19273  0.0  2.2 1400852 183680 ?      Sl   01:47   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   19290  0.0  2.2 1400852 183732 ?      Sl   01:47   0:00 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake 

[root@ip-XXX ec2-user]# ps auxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
webapp   14158  0.0  2.2 827056 187972 ?       Sl   Nov23   4:24 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   13563  0.0  2.2 1400644 185700 ?      Sl   01:41   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   13866  0.4  2.3 694804 193620 ?       Sl   01:42   0:11 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   14029  0.0  2.2 1400912 184412 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   14046  0.0  2.2 1400912 184372 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   14048  0.0  2.2 1400912 184516 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   14073  0.0  2.2 1400912 184540 ?      Sl   01:42   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   19139  0.4  2.3 694876 193428 ?       Sl   01:47   0:11 /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   19273  0.0  2.2 1400852 184288 ?      Sl   01:47   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   19290  0.0  2.2 1400852 184472 ?      Sl   01:47   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   19293  0.0  2.2 1400852 184488 ?      Sl   01:47   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
webapp   19333  0.0  2.2 1400852 184420 ?      Sl   01:47   0:00  \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/    rake                                                              
root     21038  0.0  0.0 217276  3460 ?        Ssl  01:55   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
webapp   21041  0.1  0.0 704036  5652 ?        Sl   01:55   0:02  \_ PassengerHelperAgent
webapp   21047  0.0  0.0 243944  7840 ?        Sl   01:55   0:00  \_ PassengerLoggingAgent
root     21056  0.0  0.0  56404  1016 ?        Ss   01:55   0:00 PassengerWebHelper: master process /    var/lib/passenger/standalone/4.0.60/webhelper-1.8.1-x86_64-linux/PassengerWebHelper -c /tmp/    passenger-standalone.e022jt/config -p /tmp/passenger-standalone.e022jt/
webapp   21057  0.0  0.0  56812  4436 ?        S    01:55   0:00  \_ PassengerWebHelper: worker process                                                                                                                                          
webapp   21058  0.0  0.0  56812  4436 ?        S    01:55   0:00  \_ PassengerWebHelper: worker process                                                                                                                                          
root     21063  0.0  0.0   8552  1104 ?        Ss   01:55   0:00 /var/lib/passenger/standalone/4.0.60/    support-x86_64-linux/agents/TempDirToucher /tmp/passenger-standalone.e022jt --cleanup --daemonize     --pid-file /tmp/passenger-standalone.e022jt/temp_dir_toucher.pid --log-f
root     21078  0.0  0.0  11600  2748 ?        Ss   01:55   0:00 /bin/bash
root     21102  0.0  0.0  54764  2556 ?        S    01:55   0:00  \_ su -s /bin/bash -c bundle exec     sidekiq -L /var/app/current/log/sidekiq.log -P /var/app/support/pids/sidekiq.pid
root     21103  8.1  2.6 1452872 212932 ?      Sl   01:55   2:27      \_ sidekiq 4.1.2 current [0 of     25 busy]                                                                                                                                 
root     21118  0.0  0.0  54768  2644 ?        Ss   01:55   0:00 su -s /bin/bash -c bundle exec rake     sneakers:run >> /var/app/current/log/sneakers.log 2>&1 webapp
webapp   21146  0.0  0.0   9476  2336 ?        Ss   01:55   0:00  \_ bash -c bundle exec rake     sneakers:run >> /var/app/current/log/sneakers.log 2>&1
webapp   21147  0.6  2.3 693604 193232 ?       Sl   01:55   0:11      \_ /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/    bin/rake                                                              
webapp   21349  0.0  2.2 1400608 184160 ?      Sl   01:55   0:00          \_ /opt/rubies/    ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   21411  0.0  2.2 1400608 183812 ?      Sl   01:55   0:00          \_ /opt/rubies/    ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   21414  0.0  2.2 1400608 183988 ?      Sl   01:55   0:00          \_ /opt/rubies/    ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   21475  0.0  2.2 1400608 183976 ?      Sl   01:55   0:00          \_ /opt/rubies/    ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake                                                              
webapp   21720  0.3  3.5 1311928 293968 ?      Sl   01:55   0:07 Passenger RackApp: /var/app/current
```

I'm not sure what spawned these processes (if it was sidekiq or sneakers or passenger). With each deploy the number seems to grow until the postgres connections are maxed out.

Is my beanstalk configuration incorrect? Can anybody help me debug this so I can figure out what's creating these processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like every time sneakers rake task was killed, it left behind orphan processes. To rectify I added this as a pre deploy hook:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04_mute_sneakers.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      initctl stop sneakers 2>/dev/null
      kill $(ps aux | grep '[/]opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake' | awk '{print $2}') 2>/dev/null
      echo "Killed Sneakers Process"
```